# Generate Django sitemap while using site framework

Tags: django, django-sites, django-sitemaps

I am using sites framework with `RequestSite` (no `SITE_ID` set) to generate content based on domain. I need to generate sitemaps for each domain with different results but I didnt find a way how to make this two frameworks work together. Is there any way to get `Site` of the current request in `Sitemap`? (getting it from `SITE_ID` config is not an option for me).

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```py
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from blog.models import Entry

class BlogSitemap(Sitemap):

    def items(self, request):
        return Entry.objects.filter(is_draft=False, site=request.site)
```

But its not possible because there is no `request` in `items()`. Is there any other way how to filter items in sitemap based on site?

Comment: I don't get the question properly. Are you trying to get the sitemap based on the requested domain? Or you want to show some specific sitemap for domain_1 and some for domain_2?

Comment: @JPG Yes, I need specific content based on domain. See updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following example:

```py
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap

from blog.models import Entry


class BlogSitemap(Sitemap):
    _cached_site = None

    def items(self):
        return Entry.objects.filter(is_draft=False, site=self._cached_site)

    def get_urls(self, page=1, site=None, protocol=None):
        self._cached_site = site
        return super(BlogSitemap, self).get_urls(page=page, site=site, protocol=protocol)
```

And in `urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {
        'sitemaps': {'blog': BlogSitemap}
    }, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),

    # ...
    # other your urls
]
```

This should work now. Let me know if you'll have any questions.

Comment: To prepare list of urls for items that will be used for sitemap. Actually weird thing, that it doesn't have this feature.